# Trying to test django app locally with foreman

Tags: django, heroku, terminal, gunicorn, foreman

I'm working on a django app and trying to use foreman to test my app locally before pushing to heroku.  I can successfully run it using python manage.py server. However when running it using forman it fails - Whenever I do a `foreman start` inside of the directory it would return me this:

```
09:21:09 web.1  | started with pid 9956
09:21:09 web.1  | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: gunicorn: not found
09:21:09 web.1  | exited with code 127
09:21:09 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

What does this mean?

Below is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi
```

Below is my requirements.txt

```
Django==1.4.3
distribute==0.6.31
dj-database-url==0.2.1
psycopg2==2.4.6
#wsgiref==0.1.2
gunicorn==0.16.1
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like gunicorn isn't installed properly on your system.
Run pip install -r requirements.txt and then manually run the gunicorn command to check it works.

Answer (score 4):

I came to this question with the same problem finding gunicorn when running 'foreman start', but eventually dug up at other sources that I was not recreating the virtualenv in a new bash session.  I had originally followed the instructions from [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#start-a-django-app-inside-a-virtualenv), but days later with new sessions, needed to remember to run

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the issue - installing separately **gunicorn** did the trick

`pip install gunicorn`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

and then reinstalling the heroku-toolbelt solved it!